# print formatted table javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, window.open

I'm trying to build a table dynamically in javascript and then allow the user to print data that are in the table using `window.open`. When the popup appears, all my table data are shown, but with no styles at all (no borders, nothing). Any idea how I can get my table to appear correctly please

Comment: Are you including the stylesheets/relevant styles on the page you are opening the new window in? As far as I know, pages opened with `window.open()` do not inherit styles from the parent window that opened them.

Comment: FYI, CSS background colors of tables are not printed. About the borders, I don't know why you didn't see it.